# Xcode Linker command failed - Directory not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am using auth0 on a React Native iOS project, and I have completed the following steps:

First you need to run the following command to install react-native-lock
`npm install --save react-native-lock`

After that, link react-native-lock with your iOS project:
`react-native link react-native-lock`

When running the above, cocoapods installs a few dependencies which all install successfully:

```
Adding Podfile to iOS project
Installing Pods
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Using Lock (1.28.2)
Using Masonry (0.6.4)
Using SimpleKeychain (0.7.0)
Using TouchIDAuth (0.2.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.
```

In my `Project > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags` I have:

```
lc++
${inherited}
-ObjC
```

However, when I build the project to my physical iPhone, I get this error for every `installed` dependency:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-acmwajylejkvendtsdryuouwuvnl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking'
```

Comment: does your project contain .pch file??

Comment: There isn't a .pch file within my app.

Comment: Okay, what OS do u have in your MAC ?

Comment: Update your OS.

Comment: I'm running OSX El Capitan version 10.11.6.

Comment: Why would this be an OS problem? When I run a local copy of my app on iOS Simulator it works perfectly. Building my app to my device throws the error.

Comment: You need to update to sierra

Comment: What would an update do for me which would resolve this problem? @BasirAlam

Comment: after u update please open the workspace not  xcodeproject

Comment: Have you updated your phone recently? iOS 10.3 is not compatible with Xcode 8.2, you need Xcode 8.3 to build for iOS 10.3 (there exists workarounds, but it's easier to upgrade Xcode). Xcode 8.3 requires macOS 10.2 or higher (Sierra).

Comment: I am running iOS 10.2 and XCode 8.2 on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suggestion :

after u update please open the **yourProject.xcworkspace** not  **yourProject.xcodeproject**

Comment: As someone without knowledge of iOS, do you have to open the xcworkspace file because the installed Pods are not included within the xcodeproject?

Answer (score 0):

Great, you have to update your OS for supporting fluently the XCODE 8.2.1 and above, some times it work within the old OS, i had faced that problem before and i snached all my hair for two days, then i updated my OS and its get fixed. you have to update your OS for fixing it, else nothing will work.

Thanks

Comment: Before I upgrade, what's the OS upgrade aiming to solve? I have been using XCode 8.2.1 for approximately 3 months, I've used cocoapods before with it and this is the first time I've encountered this problem.

Comment: @Dan go through this link https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT207536 and find your self about upgradation what you get in new OS and features. In One line i would like to Quote " The macOS Sierra 10.12.4 Update improves the stability, compatibility, and security of your Mac, and is recommended for all users. "

Comment: How would an improvement to stability, compatibility and security that help me identify why my app doesn't build within XCode?

Comment: You can't identify the problem, try it, by upgradation it will be fixed automatically. And about "improvement to stability, compatibility and security" what apples claim not by me, and i found myself fixed with the similar problem by upgrade the OS. Now it is your choice..

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after migrating to React Native 61.5 from 59. The introduction of Pods meant that we needed to change out CI (BitRise) iOS build command from:

```
xcodebuild "-project" "ios/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj" ...
```

to:

```
xcodebuild "-workspace" "ios/AwesomeProject.xcworkspace" ...
```

Everything was working fine via XCode locally, just didn't look closely enough that the CI Pipeline script. After changing, all was resolved.